# Stack Decompose into even and odd

Tags: java, methods, stack

This code decomposes the Stack into even and odd, how 
do even.push and odd.push work?

```
public static ArrayStack decompose(ArrayStack x) {
    ArrayStack y = new ArrayStack(x.size()/2);
    ArrayStack odd = new ArrayStack(x.size()/2+1);
    ArrayStack even = new ArrayStack(x.size()/2);
    while(!x.isEmpty())
    {
        odd.push(x.pop());
        if(!x.isEmpty())
            even.push(x.pop());
    }
    while(!odd.isEmpty())
    {
        x.push(odd.pop());
    }

    while(!even.isEmpty())
    {
        y.push(even.pop());
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push` methods place the object passed onto the top of the stack.

`even` and `odd` are just the names of your Stacks.